# selling a whole website with its subscribers who pay through stripe

Tags: woocommerce, payment, subscription

I use “WooCommerce Stripe Payment Gateway” plugin. Now I decided to sell the website.

How can I connect the new owner’s Stripe account (instead of mine)?

The new owner must have the data of subscribers.

Thanks in advance.

I've seen Stripe doc but I'm not sure about the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution on [WooCommerce Subscriptions FAQ](https://woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/faq/#section-49)

> **Can I change the account used for a payment gateway?**
>
> Yes, if you want to keep the same payment gateway but you have changed
> account, for example, due to a change of ownership, then it is
> possible to still use the same payment gateway on your site but please
> contact the gateway themselves and ask about transferring/migrating
> the customer information to your new account, then update any API keys
> or credentials in your WooCommerce payment gateway settings.